# Can't access some services from DNS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, amazon-route53, prometheus

Used `kops` installed Kubernetes cluster on AWS.

Used `alb-ingress-controller` to do load balancing followed the [official guide](https://github.com/coreos/alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md):

It works. Can run both `dig` and `curl` successfully.

[Another sample](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/apn/coreos-and-ticketmaster-collaborate-to-bring-aws-application-load-balancer-support-to-kubernetes/): `2048-game` got `504 Gateway Time-out` error when access it from `Record Set` name in `Route 53`:

http://2048.mysite.com

But can been accessed from DNS name found from `Load Balancers`! So it seems that the `Alias Target` in `Route 53` not work!

And, for `Prometheus`, used official chart to deploy and can dig successfully.

```
helm install prometheus
```

But can't run `curl` to get result:

```
curl server.mysite.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to server.mysite.com port 80: Connection refused
curl alertmanager.mysite.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to alertmanager.mysite.com port 80: Connection refused
curl pushgateway.mysite.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to pushgateway.mysite.com port 80: Connection refused
```

I checked all the services in the Kubernetes cluster:

```
$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
2048-game     service-2048                                  NodePort    100.68.230.211   <none>        80:31652/TCP    1h
default       kubernetes                                    ClusterIP   100.64.0.2       <none>        443/TCP         4d
default       steely-wombat-prometheus-alertmanager         ClusterIP   100.71.21.190    <none>        80/TCP          5m
default       steely-wombat-prometheus-kube-state-metrics   ClusterIP   None             <none>        80/TCP          5m
default       steely-wombat-prometheus-node-exporter        ClusterIP   None             <none>        9100/TCP        5m
default       steely-wombat-prometheus-pushgateway          ClusterIP   100.65.72.250    <none>        9091/TCP        5m
default       steely-wombat-prometheus-server               ClusterIP   100.65.239.188   <none>        80/TCP          5m
echoserver    echoserver                                    NodePort    100.64.176.267   <none>        80:31281/TCP    1h
kube-system   default-http-backend                          ClusterIP   100.71.27.31     <none>        80/TCP          3h
kube-system   kube-dns                                      ClusterIP   100.64.0.19      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   4d
kube-system   tiller-deploy                                 ClusterIP   100.70.101.11    <none>        44134/TCP       4d
```

I found that sample apps `echoserver` and `2048-game` are `NodePort` type. The `Pormetheus` services are `ClusterIP` type. Is `NodePort` type necessary here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the AWS Route 53 dashboard to see if the setting are ok?

Could you post the output of dig?